# Where I must save my input value? - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, syntax

So, here's two ways that I know to store  value in React. Initialize this.state variable and store data there ( this.setState({}) ) or refs (this.refs.nodename.value). I'd like to use refs, because that's need less number of lines. But what's better for perfomance? This question for you, reactjs masters.

Thanks.

```
<input onChange={ ({ target }) => this.setState({ value: target.value }) } />
// Or
<input ref="somename" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The performance question here is not relevant (nor is there a big difference).

What is relevant is the way you look at the code.

`ref` is an escape hatch, it grants you access to the underlying DOM, which React supposedly abstracts away from you (When you work with just React properly and no refs or dangeourslySetInnerHTML, your code is never aware that the DOM even exists). This is called **leaky abstraction** and in a very general way of speaking, it's a Bad Thing™

Also to note: Your second example is deprecated. In a future React version, string refs will not be allowed.

The correct form is something like

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.inputRef = null;
  }

  render() {
    // ...
    <input ref={ref => this.inputRef = ref} />
  }
}
```

Not that glamorous anymore ;)

---

My personal preference is to avoid refs as much as possible, and only use them as the last-resort, escape hatches that they are meant to be.

Comment: Ohh.. Thanks a lot for your explaining :)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a lot of people use the following format:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inputText: ''
    }
  }

  onSubmit() {
    callSomeOtherFn(this.state.inputText);
    this.setState({
      inputText: ''
    })
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      inputText: e.target.value
    })
  }

  render() {
    <input value={this.state.inpuText} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
    <button onClick={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>Submit</button>
  }
}
```

And manage forms/inputs from state